# CSS Attribute selector contains element selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

While creating my site, I found the following style being automatically applied by Chrome (despite using a clear css file):

```
input[type="search" i] {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

I believe that 1px padding is messing up the layout of my site, but for the life of me, I can't get rid of it.  I believe it has to do with the `i` inside of the input tag, which I've never seen before.

What does that `i` mean inside of the attribute selector?

Comment: I'm going to enjoy marking these duplicates every time they come up. And don't worry, it's not your fault - this sort of thing isn't particularly search-friendly. It's just nice to see this question keep coming up, because it means people are discovering this new feature and are curious about it.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you. I really did try to search for it :)

Comment: Hmm it is interesting that you can't get rid of the padding though. If you tried overriding it with the same selector `input[type="search" i]`, it may be because, as I mention in the dupe, Chrome does not allow it in author CSS by default. `input[type="search"] { padding: 0; }` *should* do the trick.

Comment: @BoltClock I've tried doing that even with an important tag, and chrome's inspector is saying its not overridden when it really is, or it isn't working